# "It did the job" meaning

Tags: phrases

Does it mean "it could be better but is ok" (small disappointment), or "it really worked!" (surprise and content)? Depends on the context?

Also, is there a difference between "That did the job" and "It did the job"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use it either way - everything depends on the context, and your intonation when you say it.  However, I'd say there's a slight bias toward "small disappointment" - especially if you preface it with "well": **Q:** *I heard you ran out of deviled ham at your cocktail party, and served cat food instead.  How did that work out for you?* **A:** *Well, it did the job... everybody went home.*

As for the That/It distinction, you can use "That did the job!" in an enthusiastic, positive sense, whereas "It did the job" would sound odd except as the answer to a question, and (as I mentioned above) it would more likely be used to [damn with faint praise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/damn+with+faint+praise).

Answer (score 5):

It's context-dependent.

Negative:

> Bill: What do you drive?
>
> Bob: An old Honda Civic.  It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.

Positive:

> Bill: Did you install the new software update?
>
> Bob: Yes, and it did the job!  The program no longer crashes!

Comment: I would not necessarily talk about disappointment in the first case. Bob could just not care about looks and be content. I agree with you it's very context dependent.

Comment: @nico You're right.  I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon they both mean the [same thing:](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+the+job)

> It achieved the desired results

Example: "Smithy kicked the faucet really hard. That did the job, the water started flowing again."

They mean the same anywhere.